# Node.js child_process spawnSync catch errors from python script

Tags: python, node.js, child-process, spawn

I am using child_process spawnSync method to run some python scripts, its all working but im unable so far to catch the errors thrown by python in try/catch blocks and it would be good if i also could catch errors raised manually from python.

**Example:**

**Node.js**

```
try {
        const process =
          await spawn('python3', [ Helpers.resourcesPath('pythonScripts/main.py'),
            debug_mode,
            lang
          ], { input: '"' + front_img + '""' + back_img + '"' });

        const errorText = process.stderr.toString().trim();

        if (errorText) {
            return response.badRequest({
                message: errorText
            });
        } else {
            return response.success({
                message: process.stdout.toString().trim()
            });
        }
    } catch(e) {
        return response.badRequest()
    }
```

**Python**

```
try:

    ocr = tool.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(img))

    for key, words in languages.items():

        result = [x.strip() for x in words.split(',')]

        if any(x in ocr for x in result):
            languageDetected = key

            if languageDetected: break

    if languageDetected:
        return languageDetected
    else:
        # I want also to be able to get this as a error in node.js
        raise Exception('Language not detected')
        sys.exit(1)

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    sys.exit()
```

In this example, if in the python code a error is caught in the catch(e) it will return it to process.stdout instead process.stderr, i want to be able to check if its either a error was returned or a good response in node.js.

It would be good if i could also caught this exception throwed manually in node.js

```
raise Exception('Language not detected')
```

Answer (score 0):

child_process can listen to errors during execution, try this :

```
const chid_proccess = require('child_process').spawn;


let main_spawn_process = chid_proccess('run some foo')

main_spawn_process.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I need it to be synchronous

Comment: I already tried it this way, it seems there is no standard between python error and `on('error')` of node child process spawn. The error catching only have to do with mode environment itself in child process. Maybe the proper way if to catch python error and print them with prefix, and receive all in `on('data')` and check if it's an error with prefix to treat or throw your own error.